# How does a second physical publisher get notified of new subscribers?

Tags: nservicebus, publish-subscribe

Related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5115012/nservicebus-how-to-publish-message-from-2-physical-locations-of-1-logical-service):
As I understand it, two physical publishers represent a single logical publisher must each have their own subscription queue.  Using DBSubscriptionStorage allows them to have a common list of subscribers, but what happens when a new subscriber pops up and subscribes?  The subscribe message will go onto one of the subscription queues and then into the database. Is there any way, short of restarting the other publishers, that they can be made aware of the new subscriber?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 Physical Publishers with Many Subscribers

Configuration

- Every endpoint(publisher or subscriber) has its own input queue.
- Each Publisher will be configured to point to the same shared subscription database
- Each Subscriber will be configured to point to one Publisher input queue(this is where they will drop their subscription messages)

Processing

1. Subscriber1 places a subscription message(M1) into Publisher1's input queue
2. Publisher1 saves that subscription into the database
3. Subscriber2 places a subscription message(M2) into Publisher2's input queue
4. Publisher2 saves that subscription to the database
5. Publisher1 publishers M1 which is placed into Subscriber1's input queue
6. Same occurs for Publisher2 and M1

You will have to decide if all Subscribers are interested in the same messages.  It is ok to have both Publishers publish the same messages as each Subscriber will only subscribed once(either at P1 or P2).  You have full control on how to "load balance" the work.  More information can be found [here](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/messaging/publish-subscribe/) if you haven't looked at it already

Comment: Maybe I'm being dense, but what I want to happen is that step 5 should multiplex the message to both S1 and S2 (which are logically and physically distinct "services" that process some of the same event types as each other, I'm not trying to load-balance.)  It seems to me that S2 cannot receive messages that originate from P1 until P1 refreshes its subscription info from the database (which wold require a restart, I think?)

Comment: P1 does not need to be restarted, it will ping the database for the list of subscribers every time.  As long as S1 and S2 are subscribed to P1, it will iterate over the list and send a message to each subscriber.

Comment: Thanks for the info, this was the crux of my question.  When you say that it will ping the db "every time", what do you mean exactly? (Every time it publishes a message? That doesn't seem likely, for performance reasons)

Comment: The subscription database schema is one table with one row per subscription/message combo and therefore is pretty lightweight.  The Publisher cannot cache the subscriptions since new subscribers can pop up at any time.

Comment: Maybe I'm being dense, but I don't know if I'm clear.  Are you saying that Publisher1 publishing message M1, and Subscriber1 and Subscriber2 will BOTH receive a message b/c they are both in the database subscription storage table?  Or P1 publishing will ONLY send a message to S1, because S1 sent a subscription message ONLY to P1?

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options.  One of the easiest is to have each of the separate physical publishers pointing to a single physical subscriber/subscription database.

Another really good way to handle it is with database replication.  The only problem with replication is that it's inherently "one way".  Even so there's a really interesting project for MySQL called "[MySQL MMM](http://mysql-mmm.org/)" that seems to be a perfect fit for this scenario.

Finally, you could potentially have your own subscription storage using something like Membase which is a persistent, replicated key/value store.

Bottom line: you can have a single subscription database which is the easiest, but you have a failure point.  Or you can have a replicated subscription storage.  The replicated storage will ensure that all nodes have a list of all subscribers.

Comment: I am using a shared db.  So do publishers poll the database to get any new subscribers which may have appeared?  They can't share a subscription queue if they are on different machines, right?

Comment: The publishers will poll just as subscribers always subscribe when starting up.

Comment: @Adam Fyles  Maybe I'm missing something.  Do the physical subscribers (on different machines from each other) somehow share the subscription queue?  I thought that wasn't possible.

Comment: Or, more precisely, the comment from some of the NSB config files scared me off from doing this: "2. Input queue must be on the same machine as the process feeding off of it."  Perhaps applies to subscriber input queues and not publishers'?